# kdevelop 4.0 : No project Templates

Tags: ide, gtk, kdevelop

I have just installed kdevelop 4.0 on my Ubuntu machine and found that there are very few project templates (all are Qt related). I am not a qt developer and the previous versions of kdevelop had a lot of project templates. I am not sure how to get general C and C++ GTK templates.

A Screenshot from a older version of kdevelop: http://www.euclideanspace.com/software/language/cpp/kdevelop/kd2.gif

Comment: random note: kdevelop 4.0 is way too old, please update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ubuntu, try installing the `kapptemplate` package. It doesn't contain as many templates as kdevelop 3 but many more than the predefined.

Answer (score 1):

just execute this command and you will have some new templates

**sudo apt-get install kapptemplate**

Answer (score 0):

At this time there are no general C or C++ GTK templates in KDevelop 4.

Comment: Seems there are still no general C templates in KDevelop 4.7.3.