# How to create a C project?

Tags: c, kdevelop

I'm using Kdevelop to create C++ projects.  Now I need to create a C project.
In 3.xx versions, I had the option to create C projects, but now I'm using Kdevelop 4.2 and I only can see C++ project templates( QT / NOGui ).

How should I configure Kdevelop for C projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the "show all project templates" while you were in the New Project dialog box? See this question as reference (look at the screenshot): [kdevelop 4.0 : No project Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595321/kdevelop-4-0-no-project-templates)

Comment: I see a little diference... check it: ttp://i54.tinypic.com/fbapo9.png... i cant see "show all project templates" :-\ Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3):

i know this is an old post but just in case .. here is a quick answer - requires a little thinking but not difficult.

1. (optional) install kapptemplate - this will put even more templates here:

   /usr/share/kde4/apps/kdevappwizard/
2. first step is just to provide more defaults - these will show up in kdevelop or you can run kdevappwizard alone. this is what will be in the directory:

   ```
   ├── kdevappwizard.rc
   ├── template_previews
   │   ├── akonadi-resources.png
   │   ├── akonadi-serializer.png
   │   ├── default-kdevelop.png
   │   ├── default.png
       ...
   └── templates
       ├── akonadiresource.tar.bz2
       ├── akonadiserializer.tar.bz2
       ├── cmake_plaincpp.tar.bz2
       ├── cmake_qt4core_qtest.tar.bz2
       ...
       └── simple_phpapp.tar.bz2
   ```
3. copy a couple of the simple ones, say simple_phpapp.tar.bz2 and cmake_plaincpp.tar.bz2 into a sandbox dir and unpack them.
4. then, check out what is there and use the files and the naming scheme of the files as a model - adjust to suit your needs and
5. pack up in similar fashion,
6. place in same directory as above or in ~/.kde/apps/kdevappwizard/..etc. - et voila!

   Note: the preview image is optional - you can skip it.`

   eh - i know, thats kinda vague but if you can program in C you can probably handle it :)

Comment: Thanks, now I can start hacking up my own templates

Answer (score 1):

To use them just copy the archives to  /usr/share/apps/kdevappwizard/templates/

CMake template: https://sourceforge.net/projects/otzy-007.u/files/cmake_plainc.tar.bz2/download

Makefile template: http://opendesktop.org/content/show.php/Simple+C+Makefile+Template?content=138514